# Sorting an Array in Java, then printing it

Tags: java, arrays

I have an error in my code, since it is not printing all of the elements of the array after it's been sorted. Can someone spot it and help me out? (I am only in my 5th week of Java, so definitely a newbie!)

```
public class Test01 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 3, 5, 4, 2};        
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) { 
        int currentMin = arr[i];
        int currentMinIndex = i;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (currentMin > arr[j]){
                    currentMin = arr[j];
                    currentMinIndex = j;
                }
            }
            if (currentMinIndex != i) {
                arr[currentMinIndex] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = currentMin;    
            }
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
}
}
```

The current output for this is: 
1 2 3 4

So I am just missing printing the '5'

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are running the loop an index short. Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {  // The -1 is the issue
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks - That seems to have worked - I was following something in my textbook that uses: 
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
in the first “for” loop. Is there a reason why that was done? The comment for it is: 
    //Find the minimum in the array[i..arr.length-1]

Comment: @bacon Dont forget to accept/vote the answer if it helped

Comment: Was the condition "less than or equal to" `i <= arr.length -1` ? because then you would need the `-1` at the end. The basic logic is that you have to iterate over the array keeping in mind that the indices of an array start with 0 and not 1 and therefore the index at "size of array" will result in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` since you will be accessing something that was not part of the array boundries

Comment: No, it wasn't. it may be an error in the book, but I will go over it with my instructor. thanks for the help!  PS - I accepted the answer, but since I am a new account, my votes are not public.

Comment: Possible a typo in the book. The mistake is quite common, even I sometimes run into it (a confession) !

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test01 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] arr = {1, 3, 5, 4, 2};
         for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int currentMin = arr[i];
            int currentMinIndex = i;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (currentMin > arr[j]){
                    currentMin = arr[j];
                    currentMinIndex = j;
                }
            }
            if (currentMinIndex != i) {
                arr[currentMinIndex] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = currentMin;
            }
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }    
    }
}
```